# Sidebar div is not filling 100% of the parent

Tags: css, layout, html

I'll try and explain this the best I can.

First of all, here is a mock up of my problem
http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7370/problemfb.png

DIV A and DIV B are inside a div called contents.

Here is the CSS:

```
#contents { height: auto; border: 1px solid black; }  
#a { float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; width: 587px; }  
#b { border-left: 1px solid black; float: right; height: 100%; width: 300px; }
```

DIV A contains the generated page content.
DIV B contains two child divs which provide tools for the page. These are both identical, and only set a height of 150px each.

The issue is that, as seen in the mock up, the #b div does not fill 100% of #contents. So when the generated content consumes > 300px, the black line seperating the right bar does not draw the entire vertical length of #contents.

I am using

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"&gt;
```

For the doctype.

Comment: You can try setting display: inline-block; on #b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [faux background technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/), [CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail) (possibly with `table-cell`) or [JavaScript](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/).

I used `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to do it.

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
#contents { display: table; }  

#a { width: 587px; }  

#b { display: table-cell; width: 300px; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/uEpBk/).

Note that this will not work < IE8.